# Crosstable missing in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 3 tables : Posts, Tags and PostTags. The PostTags table is a cross table between Posts and Tags that explains what tags that is bound to the post (this relation is setup in the MS SQL database).

The problem is that the PostTags is not visible in the Add tab of **Update Model From Database**? And its not added when adding Posts and Tags table? If I switch to refresh tab I will however see the PostTags table?

There is also no PostTag table in the Model Browser > MainModel > Entity Types?

I can see that a reference is created to the Tag table directly from the Posts in code but when trying this : Posts.Tags.Add it will demand a Tags entity and not a PostTags entities? If I run this anyway it will complain about that a column in Tags can´t be set to null. I don't want to add anything to Tags table, only to the PostTags table?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal functionality.

If you have a table (PostTags) that is a link between 2 other tables, then it will show up in the model as a many to many relationship between Posts and Tags.

If you want to see the connection table, add an extra field to the PostTags table.

If you open the model and view the xml source, you can see how it works.

**Edit**

If you have a line like this:

```
myPost.AddTag(myTag);
```

This connects the post and the Tag. When you call SaveChanges, EF will add an entry in the PostTags table.

Comment: Okay I did suspect that but how do I add tags to post then? This will mean that I need to add rows to the PostTags table. If I Type Post. I will only get Tags and if I try to add a tag here it will demand a Tags entity(not right).